# I need to generate a custom drawable view as mentioned

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-custom-drawable

[image]

I am stuck with generating custom drawable of the above type.I am able to make  cicular selector button as it is shown in in red and green border. But i am unable to make the other drawable that includes these two buttons which is in grey color and dark grey color border. And i also don't understand how to place the circular buttons at right positions.

Comment: you need a console image as png then you can overlay the buttons in it inside a relative layout.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Using 9 patch wont work as i need to place my two circular buttons at correct positions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this, This will give you the desired result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- THE VIEW THAT HOLD THE BACKGROUND -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/temp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!--TAKES UP 50%-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Left" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The width of this view should be the width of the center portion(excluding the cirlces)-->
    <!-- I have taken 60 after measuring.-->
    <View
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!--TAKES UP 50%-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Right" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I have done is simple. Put your image in background, to divide the area in two, used weights.

P:S Temp is the background file.

**Result :**

[image: **Result :**]